# Filling javascript array with php array and foreach

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, foreach

So first I get all data from `mysql` database using :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM locations";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $locations[] = $row;
}
```

And I have `map.js` file in which I have array for markers:

```
markersData = {
        'locations': [
        {
            type_point: 'TravelGuide',
            location_latitude: 45.39579812501628,
            location_longitude: 14.801673889160156,
            map_image_url: 'img/thumb_map_must_8.jpg',
            name_point: 'TravelGuide',
            description_point: 'Palazzo Strozzi 9, Florence',
            get_directions_start_address: '',
            phone: '+3934245255',
            },
        {
            type_point: 'TravelGuide',
            location_latitude: 45.39579812501628,
            location_longitude: 14.801673889160156,
            map_image_url: 'img/thumb_map_must_8.jpg',
            name_point: 'TravelGuide',
            description_point: 'Palazzo Strozzi 9, Florence',
            get_directions_start_address: '',
            phone: '+3934245255',
            }
```

And what I would like is to fill this array with `php` array but I would need to use `foreach` for that so I can load as many locations as I want. So it would be like this:

```
type_point: 'TravelGuide',
        location_latitude: $all['coordlat'],
        location_longitude: $all['coordlng'],
```

with `foreach($locations as $all)`

And one of the arrays is this

```
[ {"id":"98",
   "ime1":"TravelGuide",‌
   "i‌​me2":"TravelGuide",
   "adresa":"",
   "email":"",
   "mobitel":"(+385) --____",
   "telefon":"(0__) -",
   "koordinate":"45.39579812501628, 14.801673889160156",
   "kategorija":"Apartman",
   "opis1":"Proba za travelguide",
   "opis2":"Travelguide test",
   "aktivno":"1",
   "photo":"gen‌​eric.jpg"
  }
 ]
```

Comment: sounds like a well thought out plan of attack on this problem

Comment: That javascript array can easily be generated by `json_encode($phpArray)` As what you want is basically JSON's prime function

Comment: someone editet it..can you help now?

Comment: Well you could start by changing `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` and then you would only get ONE of each of your columns reported in the resulting array. And it would have a name and not a number

Comment: did that..thanks :)

Comment: Then if you changed your query to produce the correctly named columns for the array you want to send to javascript, most of the work would be done, i.e `SELECT id as type_point, ime1 as name_point.....`

Comment: But how can I connect my db.php where I fetch data to map.js ?

Comment: Well the obvious answer would be to make an AJAX call to dynamically load the data. But I guess thats where you are going to need a programmer to help you

Comment: can I make .js file .php and put the javascript in <script> tags?

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: that worked :)..where should i put SELECT id as ..?
Inside php or script tags?

Comment: Amend the query you ran to extract this info from your database